# How to convert tensorflow variable to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to create a model graph where my input is tensorflow variable which I am inputting from my java program
In my code, I am using numpy methods where I need to convert my tensorflow variable input to numpy array input

**Here, is my code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
eps = np.finfo(float).eps
EXPORT_DIR = './model'

def standardize(x):
   med0 = np.median(x)
   mad0 = np.median(np.abs(x - med0))
   x1 = (x - med0) / (mad0 + eps)
   return x1

#tensorflow input variable
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="input")
with tf.Session() as session:
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
 #Converting the input variable to numpy array
 tensor = a.eval()

 #calling standardize method
 numpyArray = standardize(tensor)

 #converting numpy array to tf
 tf.convert_to_tensor(numpyArray)

 #creating graph
 graph = tf.get_default_graph()
 tf.train.write_graph(graph, EXPORT_DIR, 'model_graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

**I am getting error**: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float in line *tensor = a.eval()*

When I am giving constant value in place of placeholder then it's working and generating the graph. But I  want to input from my java code.
Is there any way to do that or do I need to convert all my numpy methods to tensorflow methods

Comment: Are you just converting to numpy and back to standardize? I would rather do that directly in TF. Nevertheless what might be missing above is the feed_dict. Try a.eval(feed_dict={a: <your data>})

Comment: Actually, I don't have any values to feed right now because I am using this as model for my android application. Please refer [link](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) for more information

Answer (score 0):

`placeholder` is just an empty variable in tensorflow, to which you can feed `numpy` values. Now, what you are trying to do does not make sense. You can not get value out of an empty variable.

If you want to `standardize` your tensor, why convert it to numpy var first? You can directly do this using `tensorflow`.

The following taken from [this stackoverflow ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824665/tensorflow-median-value)

```
def get_median(v):
    v = tf.reshape(v, [-1])
    m = v.get_shape()[0]//2
    return tf.nn.top_k(v, m).values[m-1]
```

Now, you can implement your function as

```
def standardize(x):
    med0 = get_median(x)
    mad0 = get_median(tf.abs(x - med0))
    x1 = (x - med0)/(mad0 + eps)
    return x1
```

Comment: Its not just the standardize method but there are various other methods which are using numpy.I had already tried the above approach but there was a difference in output values. Thanks for the solution